# Least expensive way to construct cyclic list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, lazy-evaluation, circular-list

So if I want to construct a circular list of n 0's and 1 1, which of the following ways is better/cheaper? And is there an even better/cheaper way? Taking into account that n is an `Integer` and may be large (though realistically its not going to exceed 2^32).

```
aZerosAndOnes :: Integer -> [Int]
aZerosAndOnes n 
    | n >= 0    = cycle (genericReplicate n 0 ++ [1])
    | otherwise = []
```

versus

```
bZerosAndOnes :: Integer -> [Int]
bZerosAndOnes n 
    | n >= 0    = tail (cycle (1 : genericReplicate n 0))
    | otherwise = []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd definitely go with the second, because it's obviously efficient and plenty clear enough. The first will depend on whether `genericReplicate` is able to fuse with `++` in some fashion. The best way to find out for sure is to run

```
ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all whatever.hs | less
```

and pore over what it spews.

---

That said, the entire length of a cycle will actually be allocated in memory. Such is the nature of the cycle function as currently implemented, and that does not seem likely to change (barring some significant advance—foldr/build fusion does not seem to be sufficient). So you probably be better off avoiding this altogether by writing the rest of your code differently.

---

Ah yes, I thought of something else. If you consume this list in a "single-threaded" fashion, you can dispense with cycle altogether:

weirdthing n = genericReplicate n 0 ++ [1] ++ weirdthing n

and that's my final answer. This makes an infinite list instead of a cyclic list, but when `n` is big enough, that's *better*.

Comment: +1 good observation about `weirdthing`.  I wonder if it deserves more explanation though, I guess OP can always ask for more.

Comment: Thanks. If I write the infinite list recursively instead of using cycle, does that then not have to store the entire cycle?Also, I'm not sure by what you mean that `cycle` stores the entire length.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure by what you mean that `cycle` stores the entire length. Does that mean cycle evaluates the entire list and then cycles over it? Because that would fail on an infinite list, and `cycle (repeat 1)` works fine.

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka, the trouble is that you defeat the garbage collector. As long as you're holding on to a single cons of a cyclic list, it has to keep all the parts that have already been allocated live. If, however, you just make an infinite list that just *looks* the same, it's free to drop anything before the first cons you hold. It won't try to allocate the whole thing at once, but whatever's allocated will be around until it all becomes garbage at once, rather than becoming garbage incrementally.